# PHP APC under Windows, where is cache saved?

Tags: php, caching, apc

I'm using Windows 7 for my PHP development, and I just installed PHP APC Cache.
Now first thing I noticed is that when APC is enabled on my local Windows machine, requests are slower then when APC is disabled. It was strange to me at first, but then I read that when using APC cache under Windows, APC needs temp directory to save cache there.
So it seems that APC is slower because it does not save cache in RAM memory, but somewhere on disc. And this is all fine since Im only learning about APC cache.

My question is, where is this cache saved on disk? And how can I tell PHP to save cache in folder I want, lets say `c:\wamp\apache\temp\` , thats where my sessions are stored, and thats where I want my APC cache to go, since in dosent go to RAM.

Where can i set this up? Somewhere in php.ini file?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't that php extension bring a configuration?

Answer (score 1):

APC uses RAM to store the cache, regardless of the OS being used, and has no cache-based disk settings or options: http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php

Though I did find this...

http://php.net/manual/en/apc.installation.php

> Note: On Windows, APC needs a temp path to exist, and be writable by
>   the web server. It checks the TMP, TEMP and USERPROFILE environment
>   variables in that order and finally tries the WINDOWS directory if
>   none of those are set.

I don't know what this talking about. Maybe for some intermediary process. Or this could be out of date.

But you can see if TMP or TEMP has been set (it will be) and what path it is by running `phpinfo();`

Either way, I wouldn't be too surprised with APC and crashes, performance issues, blank screens, etc. I've been working with it (using WampDeveloper), and APC is quite temperamental.